# Is there a way to not change the maven project version for next development iteration during release-prepare?

Tags: java, maven

I have a use case where during release, I create a release branch and run mvn release plugin on it to release the artifacts. While doing mvn release:prepare, it expects to have a SNAPSHOT version for next development iteration. Is there a way to avoid having a SNAPSHOT project version for next dev iteration ? I intend to change the version manually if I do another release.

Comment: Why do you like to change the version manually? Release plugin supports that via `mvn release:prepare -DdevelopmentVersion=DEVVERSION -DreleaseVersion=RELEASEVERSION` ... ? Apart from that if you use release plugin it's assuming that you work via `1.0-SNAPSHOT..1.0...1.1-SNAPSHOT..1.1...1.2-SNAPSHOT` etc.

Comment: @khmarbaise Release plugin is expecting a SNAPSHOT version for next-dev cycle. Let's say I released the version 1.2.0, release plugin suggests to have 1.2.1-SNAPSHOT as next dev version. But I want the dev version to be 1.2.0 or anything without SNAPSHOT. Is this possible ?

Comment: A dev version which is the same as a release versions makes no sense..If you like to change the strategy how it works you could take a look because since 3.0.0-MX there is a possible strategy https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#releaseStrategyId and other things...

Comment: @HarshaChittepu SNAPSHOT versions for development are very handy because you can create the same version multiple times. You cannot do that properly with release versions.